# How to compare user input with local storage and update DOM whilst searching?

Tags: javascript, html, css, search, local-storage

I have a todo list where users can add notes. These notes are stored in local Storage, where the values are then displayed on the page after submitting input. I've already implemented the add notes part of the application but I also want to implement a search bar that filters the list showing only what matches the characters that the user inputs. What can I do?

```
<div class="search-container mt-1">
<div class="search">
<input id="search-term" type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Search..." oninput="search()">
<button type="submit" class="searchButton">
<i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
</button>
</div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="container">
<div class="flex justify-space">
<div class="text-space" id="scroll-container" onclick="scrollSection()">
<ul id="note"> </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
// open and close popup form
function openForm() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}
  
function closeForm() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}

const notes = document.getElementById("note");
const addNotes = document.getElementById("add-notes");

// store user input to local storage
let notesStorage = localStorage.getItem("note")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("note"))
  : [];

myForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    notesStorage.push(addNotes.value);
    localStorage.setItem("note", JSON.stringify(notesStorage));
    listBuilder(addNotes.value);
    addNotes.value = "";
});

// Displays user input from localstorage when posted
const listBuilder = (text) => {
    let note = document.createElement("li");
    note.innerHTML = text + ' <button id="trash" onclick="deleteNote(this)"> <i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i> </button>';
    notes.appendChild(note);
};

// Shows all contents in the array
const getNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("note"));
getNotes.forEach((note) => {
    listBuilder(note);
});

// Deletes notes on page
const deleteNote = (btn) => {
    let el = btn.parentNode;
    const index = [...el.parentElement.children].indexOf(el);
    notesStorage.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesStorage));
    el.remove();
};

function scrollSection() {
    document.getElementById("scroll-container").style.overflow = "scroll";
}

const searchQuery = document.getElementById('search-term').value

    for(i = 0; i < notesStorage.length; i++) {
    if(searchQuery === notesStorage[i]) {
        return listBuilder(note)
    }
    }
```

Comment: You "want to implement a search bar that filters the list showing only what matches the characters that the user inputs"? Ok cool, good luck with that. If you need any help come back to SO and ask a qeustion with details like code you tried so far :)

Comment: I've added my attempted code. Please provide insight.

Answer (score -1):

To implement a search bar that filters your list of notes based on user input and updates the DOM, you can follow these steps using JavaScript:

1. Retrieve data from local storage and initialize your notes list.

```js
// 

    Retrieve notes from local storage (assuming you stored them as an array of strings)
    let notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes')) || [];
```

2. Create a function to render the notes on the page.

```js
function renderNotes() {
  const noteList = document.getElementById('note');
  noteList.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the previous list

  notes.forEach((note) => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = note;
    noteList.appendChild(li);
  });
}
```

3. Create a function for the search functionality.

```js
function search() {
  const searchTerm = document.getElementById('search-term').value.toLowerCase();

  const filteredNotes = notes.filter((note) =>
    note.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
  );

  // Update the DOM with the filtered notes
  notes = filteredNotes;
  renderNotes();
}
```

4. Ensure that you call `renderNotes()` initially to display all notes, and then use the `search()` function to filter notes as the user types.

```js
renderNotes();
```

5. Attach the `search` function to the input field's `oninput` event.

```html
<input id="search-term" type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Search..." oninput="search()">
```

With these steps, your page should update the list of notes as the user types into the search input field, filtering the notes based on their content and updating the DOM accordingly. Make sure to adjust the code according to how your notes are stored in local storage.

Comment: I've added this code however, if I already have notes showing, and I search for an item, and I clear my search input, the DOM does not return to it's original notes. What is the issue that is causing this?